# MongoDB Replace the whole Doc with id 1

Tags: mongodb

Que. Replace the whole document whose _id is 1.

> db.emp.save( {_id:1} )

Is It Right or Not ?

Comment: replace with what?

Comment: Replace the whole document whose _id is 1.

Comment: When you replace, you remove the existing and update with a newer document. Was asking about that document.

Answer (score 1):

You ar probably looking for [`replaceOne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.replaceOne/) method of mongodb. It can be used as:

```
db.restaurant.replaceOne(
      { "_id" : "1", "somfield" : "Old value" },
      { "_id" : "1", "somfield" : "New value", "additional" : "addedField" }
   );
```

***Note*** - The first parameter if the filter for the document to be replaced and the second is the document which would replace it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's jump in to the shell and just take a look at the `save` method

```
> db.test.save
function (obj, opts) {
    if (obj == null)
        throw Error("can't save a null");

    if (typeof(obj) == "number" || typeof(obj) == "string")
        throw Error("can't save a number or string");

    if (typeof(obj._id) == "undefined") {
        obj._id = new ObjectId();
        return this.insert(obj, opts);
    } else {
        return this.update({_id: obj._id}, obj, Object.merge({upsert: true}, opts));
    }
}
>
```

Now if we pull away the logic in to simple steps.

No `_id` exists on the object

- Create a new ObjectId
- Attach field to object
- Call `insert` on collection with options passed in to save

`_id` exists on the object

- Merge our passed in options with `{upsert: true}` so opt `{a: 1, b: 2 }` + `{upsert: true}` would be  `{a: 1, b: 2, upsert: true }`
- Call update on the collection with the merged options and also a query of the objects `_id`

Comment: You've earned a +1 since you explained in detail rather than giving -1